# Traversing indexes in a python list

Tags: python, list

A is a list variable defined as follows:

```
A= [10 ,78,"m",89]
```

Why is the value of `A[0]` and `A[-0]` the same when executed in the python shell?

Comment: Why is *x* + 0 the same as *x* - 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `-0` is the same *value* as `0`:

```
>>> -0
0
```

You are referring to the *same index*, the first value the list. There is no such thing as negative integer zero.

Perhaps you were looking for `-1` instead? Negative integers select from the end:

```
>>> A = [10, 78, "m", 89]
>>> A[0]
10
>>> A[-1]
89
```

Answer (score 6):

`0` and `-0` are the same thing since they are both `integer`:

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda x: 0)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
>>> dis.dis(lambda x: -0)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

However, there is a negative zero and positive zero, with `float` and `double`. And the parser doesn't skip the sign:

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda: 0.0)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0.0)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(lambda: -0.0)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (-0.0)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

In case of negative zero the last bit is `1` and in case of positive zero the last bit is `0`. You can see it here:

```
>>> from struct import pack, unpack
>>>
>>> # with float, 32th bit is 1 in negative zero
>>>
>>> '0x%.8x' % unpack('I', pack('f', -0.0))[0]
'0x80000000'
>>> '0x%.8x' % unpack('I', pack('f', 0.0))[0]
'0x00000000'
>>>
>>> unpack('I', pack('f', -0.0))[0] >> 31
1L
>>> unpack('I', pack('f', 0.0))[0] >> 31
0
>>>
>>> # same thing with double, 64th bit is 1
>>>
>>> '0x%.16x' % unpack('Q', pack('d', 0.0))[0]
'0x0000000000000000'
>>> '0x%.16x' % unpack('Q', pack('d', -0.0))[0]
'0x8000000000000000'
>>>
>>> unpack('Q', pack('d', 0.0))[0] >> 63
0
>>> unpack('Q', pack('d', -0.0))[0] >> 63
1L
>>>
```

You can read more about [IEEE floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> -0 == 0
True
```

So basically you are looking at the same element.

Comment: This test isn't really sufficient, as it produces misleading results when applied to floats: `-0.0 == 0.0` but `str(-0.0) != str(0.0)`

Comment: @Eric Agreed. But `list indices must be integers, not float`. So I was just trying to answer what the OP has really asked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused because of [one's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One%27s_complement) and [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).
In one's complement we have 2 zero's and in two's complement we have just one zero, and there is now negative or positive zero.